# Meaning of Bhagwad Gita : chapter 2 verse 8

Tags: bhagavad-gita

I have some confusion regarding Bhagavad Gita  Chapter 2 verse 8

what is  the meaning of this verse ?

> na hi prapaśhyāmi mamāpanudyād
> yach-chhokam uchchhoṣhaṇam-indriyāṇām

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
न हि प्रपश्यामि ममापनुद्याद्
यच्छोकमुच्छोषणमिन्द्रियाणाम् |
अवाप्य भूमावसपत्नमृद्धं
राज्यं सुराणामपि चाधिपत्यम् || 8||
```

Here is word to word [translation](https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/) of the above verse.

> **na**—not; **hi**—certainly; **prapaśhyāmi**—I see; **mama**—my; **apanudyāt**—drive away; **yat**—which; **śhokam**—anguish; **uchchhoṣhaṇam**—is drying up; **indriyāṇām**—of the senses; **avāpya**—after achieving; **bhūmau**—on the earth; **asapatnam**—unrivalled; **ṛiddham**—prosperous; **rājyam**—kingdom; **surāṇām**—like the celestial gods; **api**—even; **cha**—also; **ādhipatyam**—sovereignty

And here is the translation;

> I can find no means of driving away this anguish that is drying up my senses. Even if I win a prosperous and unrivalled kingdom on the earth, or gain sovereignty like the celestial gods, I will be unable to dispel this grief.

Here Arjuna is saying to Lord Krishna that he is unable to kill Bhishma, Drona and all his cousins (2:5). He is not even sure about his victory (2:6). Here Arjuna is asking to Lord Krishna that even the pleasure of heavens will be not able to dispel the grief and guilt of killing his beloved ones. Then how can he kill them just for a kingdom?

[Here](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/gita/agsgita.htm) is an alternate translation by

> I do not perceive that gaining an unrivaled and prosperous kingdom on this earth, or even lordship over all the celestial controllers will remove the sorrow that is drying up my senses.

Comment: you need to give a reference for your translation...

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda ok sir